# Finding the limit of the sequence $(1 - 1/\sqrt 2) \dotsm ( 1 - 1/\sqrt {n+1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let
>   $$
>  a_n =
>  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)
>  \dotsm
>  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}} \right),
>  \quad
>  n\geq 1.
> $$
>   Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$
>
> 1. is $1$,
> 2. is $0$,
> 3. does not exist,
> 4. is $\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}$.

I tried this using the sandwich theorem as
$$
 0
\leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{-1}{\sqrt r+1}
\leq \frac{-n}{\sqrt {n+2}}
$$ 
which goes to zero. I am not sure though.

Comment: In general, what is $a_n$? It is not clear from $\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac1{n+1} \vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\right)$

Comment: a $\sqrt{..}$ is missing?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: you mean $\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$?

Comment: @robjohn yeah edited it

Comment: $\frac n{n+2}\to1$, so the sandwich theorem doesn't apply

Comment: @robjohn edited it

Comment: @SophieClad: It seems you are trying to use the theorem that for $0\le a_n\lt1$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$ then $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-a_n\right)=0$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\ge\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and since $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\to \infty$, you get $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-a_n\right)=0$. If this is what you are trying to show, then you are right. (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using
$$
a_n=\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)
$$
then, because
$$
\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\le\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac12\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)
&=\frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34\cdots\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
a_n\le\frac1{n+1}
$$

Comment: Is my solution correct

Comment: @SophieClad: I have commented on the question.

Answer (score 1):

$(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}})^n\geq a_n=(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2})...(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}})\geq (1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2})^n$

As $(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2})<1\implies (1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2})^n\to 0$

Also $(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}})^n\approx\dfrac{1}{e^{\sqrt n}}\to 0$

Hence $\lim a_n\to 0$

Comment: Your inequalities are in the wrong direction